# pagination in javafx scenebuilder with tableview

Tags: mysql, javafx, netbeans, pagination, tableview

i have too many fields in my table and because of that i have divided the table into two first table and second table...my Question is i want to put one pagination in both table so that if i decide to move my table full of records  to the next one by pressing on my pagination ,,all my table will move together.
i try it even gave my two table different id, but if i try to put the pagination on both table nothing shows,, but if i try to put it on only one table it works alright now i've try to give the same id to both table and still it affect only one is there a mistake in my codes.(i'm new in the pagination kind of a thing so i'm having little problems with it.and i dont know how to apply scrollpane to my table so i need to go through this method in other to make my two table full of one person record need to move to another please help)

please here is my codes`enter code here`

scene fxml codes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="1402.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="hotel.management.system.AliennavigationController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@aliennavigation.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Pagination fx:id="pagination" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="208.0" prefWidth="1388.0" />
      <TableView fx:id="paginationTableview" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="1388.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" styleClass="tbTable-row-cell-white">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameofhotel" prefWidth="84.0" text="nameofhotel" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="surname" prefWidth="66.0" text="surname" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="othernames" prefWidth="81.0" text="othernames" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="nationality" prefWidth="79.0" text="nationality" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="telephone" prefWidth="90.0" text="telephone" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="profession" prefWidth="95.0" text="profession" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="maritalstatus" prefWidth="85.0" text="maritalstatus" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameofspouse" prefWidth="101.0" text="nameofspouse" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="numberofchildren" prefWidth="108.0" text="numberofchildren" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="modeoftravel" prefWidth="87.0" text="modeoftravel" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="purposeofvisit" prefWidth="99.0" text="purposeofvisit" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="countryofresidence" prefWidth="115.0" text="countryofresidence" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="numberofnight" prefWidth="94.0" text="numberofnight" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="rate" prefWidth="47.0" text="rate" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="discount" minWidth="6.0" prefWidth="54.0" text="discount" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="total" prefWidth="45.0" text="total" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
      <TableView fx:id="paginationTableview" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="214.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="1388.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" styleClass="tbTable-row-cell-white">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="dateofarrival" prefWidth="79.0" text="dateofarrival" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="dateofdepature" prefWidth="103.0" text="dateofdepature" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="issuedat" prefWidth="77.0" text="issuedat" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="no" prefWidth="71.0" text="no" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="arrivedherefrom" prefWidth="105.0" text="arrivedherefrom" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="fullname" prefWidth="79.0" text="fullname" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="purposeofvisitt" prefWidth="92.0" text="purposeofvisit" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="durationofstay" prefWidth="90.0" text="durationofstay" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="destination" prefWidth="83.0" text="destination" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="hostaddress" prefWidth="93.0" text="hostaddress" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="emailaddress" prefWidth="99.0" text="emailaddress" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="dateofdepaturee" prefWidth="103.0" text="dateofdepature" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="sex" prefWidth="74.0" text="sex" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my controller codes

```
package hotel.management.system;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author PHILSERVER
 */
public class AliennavigationController implements Initializable {

    int itemPerPage = 5;
    int from = 0, to = 0;

    @FXML
    private Pagination pagination;

    @FXML
    private TableView<TableSetterGetter1> paginationTableview;


    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TableSetterGetter1, String> nameofhotel, surname, othernames, nationality, telephone, profession, maritalstatus, nameofspouse, numberofchildren, modeoftravel, purposeofvisit, countryofresidence, numberofnight, rate, discount, total, dateofarrival, dateofdepature, issuedat, no, arrivedherefrom, fullname, purposeofvisitt, durationofstay, destination, hostaddress, emailaddress, dateofdepaturee, sex;





    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

     int count = 0;
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to register class " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2", "root", "addison");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from foreignersinformation");
            rs.first();
            count = rs.getInt(1);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

       nameofhotel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameofhotel"));
       surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("surname"));
       othernames.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("othernames"));
       nationality.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nationality"));
       telephone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("telephone"));
       profession.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("profession"));
       maritalstatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("maritalStatus"));
       nameofspouse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameofspouse"));
       numberofchildren.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("numberofchildren"));
       modeoftravel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("modeoftravel"));
       purposeofvisit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("purposeofvisit"));
       countryofresidence.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("countryofresidence"));
       numberofnight.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("numberofnight"));
       rate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rate"));
       discount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("discount"));
       total.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("total"));
       dateofarrival.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateofarrival"));
       dateofdepature.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateofdepature"));
       issuedat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("issuedat"));
       no.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("no"));
       arrivedherefrom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("arrivedherefrom"));
       fullname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fullname"));
       purposeofvisitt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("purposeofvisitt"));
       durationofstay.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("durationofstay"));
       destination.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("deatination"));
       hostaddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hostaddress"));
       emailaddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("emailaddress"));
       dateofdepaturee.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateofdepaturee"));
       sex.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sex"));

        int pageCount = (count / itemPerPage) + 1;
        pagination.setPageCount(pageCount);

        pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
    }

    public List<TableSetterGetter1> getTableData() {

        List<TableSetterGetter1> data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to register class " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2", "root", "addison");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from foreignersinformation limit " + from + "," + to);

            while (rs.next()) {
                data.add(new TableSetterGetter1("" + rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26), rs.getString(27), rs.getString(28), rs.getString(29)));
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return data;

    }

    private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
        from = pageIndex * itemPerPage;
        to = itemPerPage;
        paginationTableview.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(getTableData()));
        return paginationTableview;


    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same `fx:id` never works. A `TableView` field can only contain a reference to a single `TableView`. Furthermore placing the `TableView`s next to the `Pagination` in the `AnchorPane` is wrong. `Pagination` adds nodes returned by it's `pageFactory` as one of it's descendants, which results in on of your nodes being detached from the `AnchorPane` and becoming attached to the `Pagination` control. You could fix this by placing those `TableView`s in a common parent, e.g. a `VBox` and don't attach this node to the scene:

```xml
<children>
    <Pagination fx:id="pagination" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="208.0" prefWidth="1388.0" />
    <fx:define>
        <VBox fx:id="paginationContent">
            <children>
                <TableView fx:id="paginationTableview" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="1388.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" styleClass="tbTable-row-cell-white">
                    ...
                </TableView>
                <TableView fx:id="paginationTableview2" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="214.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="1388.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" styleClass="tbTable-row-cell-white">
                      ...
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </fx:define>
</children>
```

```
@FXML
private TableView<TableSetterGetter1> paginationTableview, paginationTableview2;

@FXML
private VBox paginationContent;

...

private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
    from = pageIndex * itemPerPage;
    to = itemPerPage;
    List<TableSetterGetter1> newData = getTableData();
    paginationTableview.getItems().setAll(newData);
    paginationTableview2.getItems().setAll(newData); // you could also use a common data list for both and only call setAll once
    return paginationContent;
}
```

---

```
int pageCount = (count / itemPerPage) + 1;
pagination.setPageCount(pageCount);
```

When the number of rows in the db table is divisible by `itemPerPage`, this results in an empty page. You should check, if `count` is divisible by `itemPerPage` before adding `1`:

```
int pageCount = (count / itemPerPage);
if (count % itemPerPage != 0) {
    pageCount++;
}
pagination.setPageCount(pageCount);
```

---

The following example uses java code to create the pagination, but you should be able to reproduce similar results using fxml:

```
public static class Row {

    private final String v1;
    private final String v2;

    public Row(String v1, String v2) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }

    public String getV1() {
        return v1;
    }

    public String getV2() {
        return v2;
    }

}

private static TableView<Row> createTable(ObservableList<Row> data, String property) {
    TableView<Row> table = new TableView<>(data);
    TableColumn<Row, String> column = new TableColumn<>(property);
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(property));

    table.getColumns().add(column);
    return table;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final int itemsPerPage = 5;
    final ObservableList<Row> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    final TableView<Row> table1 = createTable(data, "v1");
    final TableView<Row> table2 = createTable(data, "v2");
    final VBox paginationContent = new VBox(table1, table2);
    Pagination pagination = new Pagination(5);
    pagination.setPageFactory(index -> {
        // replace items in shared list with items for page
        Row[] newItems = new Row[itemsPerPage];
        final int offset = itemsPerPage * index;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
            int rowIndex = offset + i;
            newItems[i] = new Row(Character.toString((char) ('0' + rowIndex)), "index = " + rowIndex);
        }
        data.setAll(newItems);

        return paginationContent;
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(pagination);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```